# How to find the method definition for a method declaration at h file in AOSP

Tags: android

How to find the method definition for drawRect declared in frameworks/base/libs/hwui/hwui/Canvas.h

```
    virtual void drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom,
                          const Paint& paint) = 0;
```

I would like to study what the `Canvas.drawRect` does in the Java layer in the native.

```java
    public void drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
        throwIfHasHwFeaturesInSwMode(paint);
        nDrawRect(mNativeCanvasWrapper, left, top, right, bottom, paint.getNativeInstance());
    }
```

[frameworks/base/libs/hwui/jni/android_graphics_Canvas.cpp](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/libs/hwui/jni/android_graphics_Canvas.cpp;l=326;drc=fcf6420eea6ebe9b92effa8ada3ccb3f47a88d88?q=android_graphics_canvas&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain), the browser navigates to the declaration rather than the definition when I click the `->drawRect` method below.

```cpp
static void drawRect(JNIEnv* env, jobject, jlong canvasHandle, jfloat left, jfloat top,
                     jfloat right, jfloat bottom, jlong paintHandle) {
    const Paint* paint = reinterpret_cast<Paint*>(paintHandle);
    get_canvas(canvasHandle)->drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, *paint);
}
```

## Update

I found the frameworks/base/libs/hwui/hwui/Canvas.cpp file in the same directory. `get_canvas` return a `Canvas` instance, which locates at `frameworks/base/libs/hwui/hwui/Canvas.h`, then I navigate to `frameworks/base/libs/hwui/hwui/Canvas.cpp`

```
Canvas* Canvas::create_recording_canvas(int width, int height, uirenderer::RenderNode* renderNode) {
    return new uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaRecordingCanvas(renderNode, width, height);
}
```

However, I can't find `drawRect` method at `frameworks/base/libs/hwui/pipeline/skia/SkiaRecordingCanvas.cpp`

Comment: You can click "references -> overridden by" to see the one implementation.